Internal factors potentially limiting psychological flow experience
Mihaly Csikszentmihalyi named the notion of Flow to describe "a mental state in which a person performing some activity is fully immersed in a feeling of energized focus, full involvement, and enjoyment in the process of the activity", and explored in his research and described in his many books the conditions required to achieve such state and the positive consequences of doing so in various activities, from sport to education.
I read several of such books, but while such research documents the challenges to staying in flow when the conditions are not favorable, it does not seem to say anything about the (in)ability to maintain flow indefinitely  even when the conditions are maintained favorable. Yet, it seems that maintaining flow continuously for long periods of time should comes at a cost, if only physically, as the energy and macro-nutrients used by the brain during such a period get exhausted.
Is there anything known about the exhaustion of some internal resources preventing the experience of flow in humans even though the external conditions for flow are maintained, and about potential negative consequences from enjoying "too much flow". It seems important as Mihaly Csikszentmihalyi  himself mentioned in some of his books how addictive the flow experience can be, and as people design applications to maximize flow for entertainment or educational purpose.
